# Use stored procedures in MVC 5 & Entity Framework 6 code-first

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am working on my first ASP.NET MVC 5 application and I'm not sure how to call my stored procedures. When I started the project, I was using ADO.NET Entity Data Model, EF Designer, when creating the model I chose the tables and the stored procedures I wanted and it worked fine. For example, if I wanted to use a stored procedure called 'usp_RhAffSelect' I would simply do:

```
using (EmployeModele db = new EmployeModele())
        {var AffectationEmploye = db.usp_RhAffSelect(employeID, sequence).ToList();
...
```

and the result from the select query would be stored in 'AffectationEmploye'

But then I had to change my model to code first instead of EF Designer. I selected the tables I wanted (which are RhAff,RhEmp and RhEve). So I have my `MainModel.cs` (which is my `DbContext`) that describes all my tables fields inside the `OnModelCreating` method. I also have 3 partial classes (RhAff.cs, RhEmp.cs and RhEve.cs) that also describes their respective fields.

Now I don't know how to use my stored procedures. It seems that I can use the `MapToStoredProcedures` but from my understanding I can only redefine insert, update and delete queries.

How can I call a select stored procedure for my models? Or any stored procedure in particular? When I was using EF Designer, I would simply right click on a table in my edmx file and would select 'Update from database', I would choose which stored procedure I wanted and was able to use them after.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as shown below.

*Note:* This is just an example.

**SP**

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[CountOfOrders]
    @ProductId int
AS
SELECT Count(*) From Orders o 
INNER JOIN OrderDetails od ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID 
WHERE od.ProductID = @ProductId
```

**How to call it :**

```
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@ProductID", 72); 
var totalOrders = await context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("CountOfOrders @ProductID", param1).SingleAsync();
```

Please read [**Entity Framework Code First and Stored Procedures**](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/299/entity-framework-code-first-and-stored-procedures) article.